# Invalid index type "Union[int, str]" for "Union[List[Any], Dict[Any, Any]]"; expected type "int"

Tags: python, list, key, type-hinting, mypy

I had a little fight with mypy recently. Let's say i have a variable which can be a dict or a list (here *self.my_list*). Later, in a function (here: *get*), I want to access a value in this list or dict.

```
from typing import Union, Any

class my_class:
    def __init__(self, whatever: Union[list, dict]):
        self.my_list: Union[list, dict] = whatever

    def get(self, key: Union[int, str]) -> Any:
        return self.my_list[key]
```

Mypy gaves me the following error for the line where I try to access a value in *my_list*:

```
 Invalid index type "Union[int, str]" for "Union[List[Any], Dict[Any, Any]]"; expected type "int"
```

- Someone has any idea how to handle this error ?
- Is it maybe bad from start to have a variable which can be a dict or a list ?

Answer (score 1):

`mypy` is not wrong in that error. Consider this case:

- `my_list` is a `list`. This satisfies the `Union[list, dict]` type.
- `key` is a `str`. This satisfies the `Union[int, str]` type.

However, `my_list[key]` is wrong, because you can't index a list with a string. When dealing with `Union` types, `mypy` will check that the code works for *every combination* of types within `Union`s, and throw an error if any combination fails.

In general I don't think your current APIs show a good design. `my_list` is an internal attribute, its type is an implementation detail, and should not affect usage of your class. However, you're now forcing the user to remember (or worse, dynamically check) whether they have a list or a dict stored in the class, and potentially use different keys. To me, this is either unnecessary wrapping (putting things in a class where it's perfectly fine to use them directly) or improper encapsulation (the class exposing too many implementation details or deferring its responsibilities to the user).